# TypeError when calling parent class despite passing parameter

Tags: python, constructor, pyqt, qtextedit

I have a class `TextElement` which inherits from PyQt-class `QTextEdit` and a custom class `BaseElement`.
`BaseElement` needs the parameter "transmitter" which is passed by the parameter "transmitter" of `TextElement` itself.

Despite doing everthing accordingly I get the TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\HotTeacher\package\tblock.py", line 102, in insertTextElem
    TE = TextElement(self.transmitter, self)
  File "...\HotTeacher\elements\textelement.py", line 13, in __init__
    QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent=parent)
TypeError: BaseElement.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'transmitter'
```

I checked if I forgot to pass the parameter "transmitter" when an instance of `TextElement` is created but everthing seems fine.

baseelement.py

```
class BaseElement:
    def __init__(self, transmitter) -> None:
        self.transmitter = transmitter
        self.isfocussed = False
```

textelement.py

```
class TextElement(QTextEdit, BaseElement):
    def __init__(self, transmitter, parent=None) -> None:
        print(transmitter) # Just for checking if something is passes
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        BaseElement.__init__(self, transmitter)
        ...
```

This is where an instance of TextElement is created:

```
class BlockRow:
    def insertTextElem(self) -> None:
        TE = TextElement(self.transmitter, self)
        ...
```

I didn't use `super()` to call the parent classes because both need different parameters.

So why am I getting this TypeError despite every parameter is passed seemingly fine?

I've also tried to pass the parameters like this:

```
class TextElement(QTextEdit, BaseElement):
    def __init__(self, transmitter, parent=None) -> None:
        print(transmitter) # Just for checking if something is passes
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        BaseElement.__init__(self, transmitter=transmitter)
```

But this didn't work either.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I think it could be something to do with `QTextEdit`. Try using this instead: `class TextElement(BaseElement, QTextEdit):`

Comment: @quamrana Thank you! This simple change did work. But I'm curious what it has to do with ```QTextEdit```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `QTextEdit` looks a little like this:

```py
class QTextEdit:
    def __init__(self, parent) -> None:
        ...
        super().__init__()
        ...
```

The `super().__init__()` there, *accidentally* calls your `BaseElement.__init__()`.

Swapping the classes over: `class TextElement(BaseElement, QTextEdit):` means that the `super` call no longer looks into `BaseElement`.

You can get a sense of what happens if you try: `print(TextElement.mro())` for both versions of the base classes.

Comment: That's very likely because ```QTextEdit``` inherits from ```QFrame``` according to the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QTextEdit.html

Comment: Yes, I didn't actually look up the documentation, but having worked with GUI frameworks before I thought it very likely that it would use `super()` to several levels to initialise all the parents.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always consider relying on `super()` unless you really know what you're doing. Also, see [the PyQt documentation on the matter](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html), which specifically uses these aspects.